# How to make a search function that searches a table or array of product description and displays the corresponding code

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

I have a product list and I would like to implement a search function.
I have a list of products and a list of codes that correspond to it.

For example, see below codes:

```
"15L Full Bottle - 1015",
"15L Empty Bottle - 15",
"11L Full Bottle - 1011",
"11L Empty Bottle - 11",
"One Way Bottle - 1030",
"600ml Bottle - 5760",
"5L Cask - 5713",
"10L Cask - 5714",
"10L Piccadilly Cask - 5703",
"1.5L Mt Franklin Still PET - 5849",
"1.5L Neverfail Still PET - 5717",
"Cooler (Monthly Rental) - 97101",
"Cooler (Annual Rental) - 97112",
"Delivery Fee - 97550",
```

[Image of My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntm5f.png)

When i type the description of the item i would like the corresponding code to show up. I want the results to show up over the top of the product sheet.

For example: If I type `15L` it should show:

```
"15L Full Bottle - 1015"
"15L Empty Bottle - 15"
```

Comment: First of all please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Stackoverflow is a community where you can ask your doubts when you fail to achieve something after different tries. In your case you haven't tried anything. So please google for your question, find out different solutions, try some of it, and come back here when you have doubt at that time.

Comment: Just a hint, search for the word "autocomplete" with javascript or jquery. You will get a lot of websites with lots of example programs.

Comment: This is a very simple example @ w3schools - please go through https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: @smilyface thanks for your help however: i have already managed to do an autocomplete script but this only works if the word or string is written from left to right. If you type in maybe a second part of the word it doesnt come up.

Comment: in that case also, you can get it by just browsing (if you dont know to change the existing code)

Comment: Also don't forget to select the answer as right if it  worked for you :)

Comment: Andrew, Please try the below answer (I have edit it) - click on `Run code snippet` blue button

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Hope this is the one you are searching for.

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
     "15L Full Bottle - 1015",
     "15L Empty Bottle - 15",
     "11L Full Bottle - 1011",
     "11L Empty Bottle - 11",
     "One Way Bottle - 1030",
     "600ml Bottle - 5760",
     "5L Cask - 5713",
     "10L Cask - 5714",
     "10L Piccadilly Cask - 5703",
     "1.5L Mt Franklin Still PET - 5849",
     "1.5L Neverfail Still PET - 5717",
     "Cooler (Monthly Rental) - 97101",
     "Cooler (Annual Rental) - 97112",
     "Delivery Fee - 97550"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search any keyword: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```